# Por qué no puedo iniciar un objeto de una clase?

Tags: java, objeto, constructor

Necesito poder acceder a los metodos de una clase que no es static, por lo que necesito crear un objeto de esa clase para poder acceder a sus metodos verdad?

Estoy diseñando una app simple que emula a un banco, por lo que necesito poder acceder a los metodos de la clase Banco (agregarSucursal, agregarCliente, etc.)
desde Main.

Creo un objeto en main de la siguiente manera

```
private static Bank bancoPrueba = new Bank("bancoPrueba");
```

pero aun así no puedo acceder a los metodos de la clase Bank usando algo como

```
bancoPrueba.agregarSucursal
```

Es como si el objeto no estuviera creado. Por qué?

//Main

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Bank galicia = new Bank("Galicia");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printOptions();

        boolean quit = false;
        while(!quit){
            System.out.println("6. Imprimir lista de opciones");
            int option = scanner.nextInt();
            switch(option){
                case 0:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    addSucursal();
                    break;
//                case 2:
//                    imprimirSucursales();
//                    break;

//                case 3:
//                    addNewClient();
//                    break;
//                    
//                case 4:
//                    agregarTransaccion();
//                    break;
//                
//                case 5:
//                    imprimirClientesSucursal();
//                    break;
                case 6:
                    printOptions();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

//Bank

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bank {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Sucursal> sucursales = new ArrayList<Sucursal>();

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void agregarSucursal(String sucursalName){
        new Sucursal(sucursalName);

    }
```

// Sucursal

```
public class Sucursal {

    private String sucursalName;
    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    public Sucursal(String name) {
        this.sucursalName = name;
        this.clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        System.out.println("Sucursal " + name + " creada.");
    }

    public void agregarCliente(String name, double initialTransaction){
        clientes.add(new Cliente(name, initialTransaction));
        System.out.println("Cliente " + name + " agregado a esta sucursal. Transaccion inicial: " + initialTransaction);
    }

    public static void agregarTransaccion(Cliente cliente, double transaccion){
        cliente.addTransactions(transaccion); //al ser STATIC no hace falta crear un Objeto Sucursal para poder llamarlo

    }

//GETTERS SETTERS


    public String getName() {
        return sucursalName;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿No te muestra el método de la clase o te da un error al ejecutar el programa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es el acceso al método, y esto se debe a que el método esta siendo llamado desde un método estático que es `main()` , en este caso debes definir como estático (`static`) el método  `agregarSucursal()`  :

```
   public static void agregarSucursal(String sucursalName){
        new Sucursal(sucursalName);

    }
```

de esta forma lo puedes llamar como lo deseas realizar:

```
     Bank bancoPrueba = new Bank("bancoPrueba");
     bancoPrueba.agregarSucursal("Banco de 1990eam");
```

Answer (score 0):

Si bien ahora lo estoy pudiendo invocar, al crear la sucursal invocando el metodo correspondiente (que a su vez llama al constructor de Sucursal) parecería que no puedo iniciar el objeto dado que el System.out sale vacío y lo mismo si imprimo una lista de sucursales.

//Banco.agregarSucursal

```
public void agregarSucursal(String sucursalName){
    sucursales.add(new Sucursal(sucursalName));

}
```

//Banco.imprimirSucursales

```
public void imprimirSucursales(){
    System.out.println("Lista de sucursales");
    for(int i = 0; i<this.sucursales.size();i++){
        System.out.println(this.sucursales.get(i).getSucursalName());

    }


}
```

//Constructor Sucursal y getName

```
public Sucursal(String name) {
        this.sucursalName = name;
        this.clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        System.out.println("Sucursal " + name + " creada.");
    }

        public String getName() {
        return sucursalName;
    }
}
```